# re-using column specifications in tabular

Tags: tables

I have multiple tables which have a arbitrary fixed set of column specifications.
e.g

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccp{2cm}rcp{2cm}@{}}
blah
\end{tabular}
```

I would like to save and reuse the arguments `@{}lccp{2cm}rcp{2cm}@{}` over and over again for other tables.

I tried:
`\newcommand{\tabformat}{@{} etc}`

and then

```
\begin{tabular}{\tabformat}
blah
\end{tabular}
```

and I also tried spraying the code with multiple `\protect` statements, but I couldn't get it to work.

MnWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tabformat}{llrrllrr}
\begin{tabular}{\tabformat} 
blah
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype\tabformat{llrrllrr}
\begin{tabular}{\tabformat}
blah&blb & bl\\
a& b & c
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this tricking `array` into thinking that one column is being defined, whereas in fact many are?

Comment: There is no trick.\newcolumntype can be used for any part of a tabular preamble.