# Use macro argument in \multicolumn column-specification

Tags: tables, tex-core

When creating table headings, a 1-cell `\multicolumn` is often used. To simplify this, one might make a table-head macro:

```
% this definition works, but doesn't allow controlling alignment
\newcommand{\Th}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{#1}}}
```

However, we might not always want a left-aligned column; sometimes it might be more appropriate to right-align or center, etc. However, it’s very difficult to add an optional argument controlling the column specification:

```
\newcommand{\Th}[2][l]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
% when used: ! Misplaced \omit.
% \multispan ->\omit
%                    \@multispan
% l.8     \Th{Header}
%                     & \Th[r]{header (\textsc{usd})} & \Th{header} \\
```

Below are some ideas I had for potential solutions; the error messages they create are above the definition. What am I missing here?

[This answer to “re-using column specifications in tabular”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390148/94878) implies that solution #3 — which temporarily creates a new column-type and uses it — should work, but it still creates an error.

I’m also aware that the [`makecell` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) provides a partial solution via its `\thead` macro, but it’s not granularly-configurable enough — and I would like to know why these definitions don’t work either way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
% attempt #1: edef/expandafter solution
% when used: ! Use of \\Th doesn't match its definition.
% \text@command #1->\def \reserved@a {
%                                     #1}\ifx \reserved@a \@empty \let \check@...
% l.16 \Th{Header}
%                  & \Th{header (\textsc{usd})} & \Th{header} \\
\newcommand{\Th}[2][l]{%
  \edef\@multicolumncontents{{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}%
  \expandafter\multicolumn\@multicolumncontents}

% attempt #2: expandafter/begingroup solution
% when used: ! Misplaced \omit.
% \multispan ->\omit
%                    \@multispan
% l.21 \Th{Header}
%                  & \Th[r]{header (\textsc{usd})} & \Th{header} \\
\newcommand{\Th}[2][l]{%
  \expandafter\multicolumn\begingroup{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}\endgroup}

% attempt #3: newcolumntype solution
% when used: ! Misplaced \omit.
% \multispan ->\omit
%                    \@multispan
% l.31 \Th{Header}
%                  & \Th[r]{header (\textsc{usd})} & \Th{header} \\
\newcommand{\Th}[2][l]{%
  \newcolumntype\@thcol{#1}%
  \multicolumn{1}{\@thcol}{\textbf{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\Th{Header} & \Th[r]{header (\textsc{usd})} & \Th{header} \\
data        & 12831                      & data \\
1238        & 12.38                      & 4893258439 \\
$\delta$    & 10                         & 1238 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `\multicolumn` has to be “the first thing” after `&` or at the beginning of a row.

No unexpandable instructions can intervene and a command defined with `\newcommand` to have an optional argument uses `\@ifnextchar` in order to determine whether `[` follows, which eventually requires the unexpandable `\futurelet`, much earlier than the replacement text is inserted.

There is a very easy solution: use `xparse` that can define expandable commands with optional arguments, provided a mandatory one trails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\Th}{O{l}m}{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\Th{Header} & \Th[r]{header (\textit{usd})} & \Th{header} \\
data        & 12831                      & data \\
1238        & 12.38                      & 4893258439 \\
$\delta$    & 10                         & 1238 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When you use a `\multicolumn` in your tabular, the implementation achieves the desired effect by a combination of the two TeX primitives `\omit`, to remove the cell's column format, and `\span`, to "merge" two column cells into one. However, there's a restriction: If `\omit` occurs in a cell, it has to be the very first unexpandable token.

In your `\Th` version without an optional argument this is fine because there's only fully expandable commands involved here which finally results in `\omit` actually being the first unexpandable token. On the other hand, the version with an optional argument uses definitions and assignments internally which are not expandable and thus make `\omit` appear somewhere later in the token stream, hence the `Misplaced \omit` error.

So the trick is to rewrite `\Th` in a way that makes it full expandable up to the point where `\multicolumn` comes into play:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\def\Th#1#{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \expandafter\Th@@\expandafter l%
    \else
        \Th@#1%
    \fi
}
\def\Th@[#1]\fi{\fi\Th@@{#1}}
\def\Th@@#1#2{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\Th{Left} & \Th[c]{\textit{Center}} & \Th[r]{Right} \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxx & xxxx & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\Th` reads anything up until the first `{` token and checks whether the part between `\Th`and `{` is empty. If so, `\Th@@` is called with `l` as the default alignment parameter. Otherwise we parse the optional parameter via `\Th@` and call `\Th@@` with the passed alignment parameter.